# Truncate a sum in a 'smart' way

Tags: series-expansion, summation

Consider a series like this:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (c_n r^{2-n/2}+d_n r^{-n/2})$$

```
Sum[c[n]r^(2-n/2)+d[n]r^(-n/2),{n,Infinity}]
```

I want, now, to keep only the terms for which the power of $r$ is negative, i.e., the non diverging terms for $r\rightarrow\infty$, and send to zero all the `c[n]` and `d[n]` which correspond to a positive power of $r$.

After this, I would like to keep all the terms of the general sum that go to zero more slowly than $r^{2}$, e.g.the terms with $r^{-1}$, $r^{-1/2}$, with their respective coefficients. Notice that this can come from different $n$, so it is not enough in general to truncate the series.

How can I do this using `Series`? I can't manage it.

Comment: Like `Sum[If[2 - n/2 >= 0, 0, c[n] r^(2 - n/2)] + d[n] r^(-n/2), {n, Infinity}]`?

Comment: @belisarius This is not practical when I have many different expressions as exponents. In the question I used a toy sum, but in general I would need to impose many more conditions on that `If`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Piecewise` to filter out any components you do not desire:

```
(* your exclusion conditions *)
conds={2-n/2<0, (* possibly more *) };

filter[c_]:=Piecewise[{{1,And@@c}},0]
```

and then

```
Sum[filter[conds] c[n]r^(2-n/2) + filter[conds] d[n]r^(-n/2),{n,Infinity}]
```

This can easily be expanded for any conditions you might encounter.

Comment: It is a little but uncomfortable because it does not seem to work on the whole series. I mean, unless I multiply `filter[cond]` individually in front of each term that can give problems, it does not work.

Comment: If for example I have `Sum[c[n] r^(1-n/2)+d[n] r^(n/2-1),{n,Infinity}]` this will give zero

Comment: @usumdelphini: Sure you will have to filter all your expressions within the sum. I updated the answer accordingly. Were it not for an infinite sum, this would be totally different story.